# Is it possible to retrieve android app info like id, name when sending HTTP request to PHP api ?

Tags: php, android, rest, httpurlconnection

I am creating a website in which i have to verify app ownership. I am providing android code which user will paste in his app.
This code simply send HTTP request to my API server. I have printed $_REQUEST in api.php. In response $_REQUEST only returns the params i passed in app code.

Here is the android code:

```
package com.example.vasim.apisample;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static String urlString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String adSetupID = "25";
    String adSetupBannerSize = "125x125";

    // Create data variable for sent values to server
    String data = null;
    try {
        data = URLEncoder.encode("block_id", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(adSetupID, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("banner_size", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(adSetupBannerSize, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Send Request
    urlString = "http://howtocodeigniter.com/api.php?"+data;
    new ProcessJSON().execute(urlString);

}

private class ProcessJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings){
        String stream = null;
        String urlString = strings[0];

        HTTPDataHandler hh = new HTTPDataHandler();
        stream = hh.GetHTTPData(urlString);

        // Return the data from specified url
        return stream;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String stream){

        //..........Process JSON DATA................
        if(stream !=null){
            // Get the full HTTP Data as JSONObject
            //JSONObject reader= new JSONObject(stream);

            Log.e("server_response:", stream);

        } // if statement end
    } // onPostExecute() end
} // ProcessJSON class end


} // MainActivity class end
```

I am just a PHP developer, i did this android programming via online videos and articles. I am not sure if code is perfect to retrieve app info or not.

In the response i am getting :

```
E/server_response:: Array(    [block_id] => 25    [banner_size] => 125x125)
```

I want user agent data (device name, app id, user ip etc) like we fetch in PHP.

Comment: HTTP clients mostly send only what you ask it to send ... feel free to use custom or well known headers or query string ... or post body ...

Comment: @Selvin hmm.. Any other option to get it work ?

Comment: yes, only one, open it with webbrowser instead with http client it will prolly send you more information about device ... **WHAT DID YOU NOT UNDERSTAND? if you didn't send those information from client you will not get them on server side!**

Answer (score 0):

You can't get any app info if it wasn't implemented manually on Android side.

Comment: Yes you are right.. I have printed $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] and i just received Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.0; Android SDK built for x86 Build/NYC)